# Deep learning on cloud

Tags: deep-learning, efficiency, cloud-computing

I am trying to implement some deep learning models with large amount of data around 10gigabyte. Although, my Laptop and Collab-free crashes when it tries to load them. Do you think it worths to buy collab-pro? Do you suggest any other solutions? But my worries are mostly about buying collab-pro is only for US and Canada while I am from Europe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use your machine GPU?

You can use batch processing, and train you're data chunk by chunk, it will take some time to go through all of your 10GB, but it will eventually gives you the result without paying extra.

You can also create a free account on [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/gcp/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=emea-emea-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-gcp-1009139&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_359082266389-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20%7E%20EXA_1:1_EMEA_EN_General_Cloud_breakout_gcp-KWID_43700053284616774-kwd-301388847745-userloc_1012760&utm_term=KW_gcp-NET_g-PLAC_&ds_rl=1242853&ds_rl=1245734&ds_rl=1242853&ds_rl=1245734&gclid=Cj0KCQjw59n8BRD2ARIsAAmgPmKBeuxRqP31XAO-CCh6OhXGiA8ff5awQP0VwhrMWue5PS9qz4k9-gQaAu9yEALw_wcB) and they will give a 300$ worth of credits and try to execute your models...

The same with Amazon Web Serives, 100USD promotional credits for students, 150USD for educators, 30USD for other occupations [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/)

Microsoft Azure give 200USD for free too [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these as well:

- Paperspace - offers [GPU cloud](https://www.paperspace.com/gpu-cloud) for ML/DL. ([pricing](https://www.paperspace.com/pricing))
- Scaleway - offers [machine learning images](https://www.scaleway.com/en/machine-learning-images/). ([pricing](https://www.scaleway.com/en/pricing/?tags=compute))
- Genesis Cloud - offers [CPU/GPU compute units](https://www.genesiscloud.com/product/compute-instances). ([pricing](https://www.genesiscloud.com/pricing))
- Vast.ai - [rent a GPUs](https://vast.ai/). ([pricing](https://vast.ai/#pricing))